# Try/catch doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-context

I have a class to show HTTP's error messages.

According to the throwable it shows a message.

But some time I got null pointer exception

```
public static void showGeneralErrors(Throwable throwable) {
    String message = "";
    AppInitialization appInitialization = AppInitialization.getInstance();

    if (appInitialization == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
            if (((HttpException) throwable).code() == 500) {
                message = appInitialization.getString(R.string.server_error);
            } else {
                message = appInitialization.getString(R.string.parsing_problem);
            }
        } else if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
            message = appInitialization.getString(R.string.internet_error);
        }else if(throwable instanceof SSLHandshakeException){
            message = appInitialization.getString(R.string.internet_error);
        }
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
            Toast.makeText(appInitialization, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(">>>>>", "Exception network error handler " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(">>>>>", "IllegalStateException network error handler " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(">>>>>", "NullPointerException network error handler " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And error message is:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:298)

And public AppInitialization is:

```
public class AppInitialization extends Application {
private static AppInitialization mInstance;

public static synchronized AppInitialization getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mInstance = this;
}
```

And it comes from retrofit Onfailure method:

```
GeneralRepo.getCountryFromIp(getContext())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe(countryFromIPResponse -> {
        //do something
    }, throwable -> {
        // Where i got error
        NetworkErrorHandler.showGeneralErrors(throwable);
    });
```

why i got this error and why try/catch doesn't work?

Comment: because your error is not fired on that block of code , put more logcat in your answer to see the origin error.

Comment: Agree with @diegoveloper ,also check if throwable object is null

Comment: @diegoveloper Updated

Comment: could you put the code of this : AppInitialization.getInstance()  ,  your appinitialization class

Comment: Pass your Activity's context instead of Application's context to the `Toast`.

Comment: You're getting an exception when making a `Toast`. Please post the code where you do it

Comment: @diegoveloper and AppInitialization added to manifest.xml

Comment: ok so you can't use the application object as context for the Toast, you need to use an Activity context. , Toast.makeText(activity context here, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Aslo, application class instance can be obtained with `((AppInitialization) getApplicationContext)`. In this case, you will be sure that instance won't distroy.

Comment: @diegoveloper I have used activity context and i got same error

Comment: Put the code using your activity context in your answer, and put thr method getcountrybyip

Comment: @diegoveloper getcountrybyip is retrofit Get method

Comment: and which is the method for: String message = "";
    AppInitialization appInitialization = AppInitialization.getInstance();

Comment: @diegoveloper see the code, i have update it

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in this piece of code?

Comment: Would you mind posting the full stacktrace for the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Put your try catch block on else portion because NullPointerException occur

> appInitialization

is coming null so ..

write :

> public static void showGeneralErrors(Throwable throwable) {
>       String message = "";
>       AppInitialization appInitialization = AppInitialization.getInstance();
>
> ```
> if (appInitialization == null) {
>     return;
> }else{
>
>   try {           if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
>           if (((HttpException) throwable).code() == 500) {
>               message = appInitialization.getString(R.string.server_error);
>           } else {
>               message = appInitialization.getString(R.string.parsing_problem);
>           }           } else if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
>           message = appInitialization.getString(R.string.internet_error);             }else if(throwable instanceof SSLHandshakeException){
>           message = appInitialization.getString(R.string.internet_error);             }           if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
>           Toast.makeText(appInitialization, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          }       } catch (Exception e) {
>       Log.e(">>>>>", "Exception network error handler " +
> ```
>
> e.getMessage());      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
>             Log.e(">>>>>", "IllegalStateException network error handler " + e.getMessage());        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
>             Log.e(">>>>>", "NullPointerException network error handler " +
>   e.getMessage());      }   } }